# How to determine the value of a domain name?

Tags: domains, purchase

I'd like to register a second-level domain with the .com extension and I noticed that it has already been registered and the owner put it for sale and let the possibility to make an offer in their site or by contacting them.

I saw that domains are generally sold for extremely different prices, so I'm confused.

Are there any general criteria to decide how much I should offer to purchase a domain?

Comment: **Try** a **third-party** brokerage **service** if **you** are **unwilling** to **make** the **first** offer. _(also good luck, a short domain with a common name like that will cost a small fortune - many thousands of dollars minimum)_

Comment: Please do not use unnecessary formatting in your questions.

Comment: @JohnConde ok, I'm sorry (I just did it because I supposed it was a good method to help others grasping the key things which the question are concerned with)

Comment: @TomBrossman thank you for replying! Could you maybe recommend me one of them please?

Comment: @robertalrp [Recommendations](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for third-party sites and services is considered off-topic here. Many registrars offer this service, and it's easy enough to search for domain brokers. I'd really recommend contacting them anonymously with whatever you'd be willing to pay or can afford, and negotiate from there.